# ALAssetLibrary aspectRatioThumbnail iOS4

Tags: ios5, ios4, thumbnails, alassetslibrary

I'm working on a project which need to browse and display pictures present in the iPhone galleries.

I use ALAssetLibrary to do that. To generate thumbnail image i use "aspectRatioThumbnail". Everything work well and smooth on my 3GS iOS 5. But these method does not exist in iOS4.

i try to generate manually thumbnail ratio image with this function but crash due to memory warning. Log show me that the generated image size doesn't respect given constraint of max size 120.

Any ideas ?

```
    NSDate* firstDate = [NSDate date];
    uint8_t* buffer = (Byte*)malloc(_asset.defaultRepresentation.size);

    NSUInteger length = [_asset.defaultRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:_asset.defaultRepresentation.size error:nil];

NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:_asset.defaultRepresentation.size freeWhenDone:YES];
                                  nil];

        NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat,
                           (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
                           (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways,
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:120], kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize,
                           nil];

        CGImageSourceRef sourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)data, (CFDictionaryRef) options);
        CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(sourceRef, 0, NULL);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(sourceRef, 0, imageProperties);

        image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

        NSTimeInterval tic = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
        NSLog(@"Thumbnail generation from ios4 method %f [size %f * %f", tic, image.size.width, image.size.height);

        [data release];
        CFRelease(sourceRef);
        CFRelease(imageRef);
        CFRelease(imageProperties);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above has a lot of unnecessary copying. Instead, just load the image at screen resolution (smaller than the full image size) and downsize to a thumbnail from there:

```
CGImageRef img = [[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage];
int w = CGImageGetWidth(img);
int h = CGImageGetHeight(img);
float scale = 120 / (float)(MAX(w, h));
CGSize newsize = CGSizeMake(w * scale, h * scale);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newsize);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, newsize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, newsize.width, newsize.height), iref);
UIImage* thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

After running this code, thumbnail will have a UIImage that is equivalent to the aspectRatioThumbnail.